# PHP session variable not being saved

Tags: php, html, session-variables

I am creating a survey based on a PHP script. The script re-loads itself with a different set of videos to be rated and a set of radio buttons to choose from after clicking a "submit" button.

I have the problem that my scores are not being saved in the Session variable. When I print it, it is empty.

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
    $_SESSION['rating2'] = $_POST['score2'];
}
?>

<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
  <?PHP echo "<embed src='$video1' width='400' height='400'>"; ?>
  <br/><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="score2" value="A"> <?php echo "A"; ?>
  </td>
  <td>
  <?PHP echo "<embed src='$video2' width='400' height='400'>"; ?>
  <br/><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="score2" value="B"> <?php echo "B"; ?>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<form action="setup2.php?video=<?php echo $nextvideo; ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit">
```

Apologies if that looks messy, I'm very new to PHP and hope that someone can point me into the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: I don't  see your radio buttons between the form element why is that?

Comment: can you add the code where you actually try to access $_SESSION['rating2'] and where you post the current score? You are currently saving the value of a radio button as score - correct?

Comment: First step: Do `var_dump()`'s of the variables involved and then you will probably see that the problem is not related to the session.

Answer (score 1):

Pull your radios into the form

```
<form action="setup2.php?video=<?php echo $nextvideo; ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit">
  <input type="radio" name="score2" value="A"> <?php echo "A"; ?>
  </td>
  <td>
  <?PHP echo "<embed src='$video2' width='400' height='400'>"; ?>
  <br/><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="score2" value="B"> <?php echo "B"; ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are calling it 'score' since you are saving Chars - but here is what i would expect it to do:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
    $_SESSION['rating2'] = $_POST['score2'];
}
?>
<form action="setup2.php?video=<?php echo $nextvideo; ?>" method="post">
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>
      <?PHP echo "<embed src='$video1' width='400' height='400'>"; ?>
      <br/><br/>
      <input type="radio" name="score2" value="A"> <?php echo "A"; ?>
   </td>
   <td>
       <?PHP echo "<embed src='$video2' width='400' height='400'>"; ?>
       <br/><br/>
       <input type="radio" name="score2" value="B"> <?php echo "B"; ?>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>


<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit">
</form>
```